# converting string to Schema.SObjectField

Tags: apex, rest, describesobject

I have created an API But struggling in converting `String` to `Schema.SObjectField` as If there is any possible way to cast string into `Schema.SObjectField` field type for example `Account.example__c` to `Schema.SObjectField`.

And if not can we seprately bind and concate them.

Comment: Is 'Account.example__c' the string you're trying to convert?

Comment: Yep it could be of any type as in generic For example  object/customobject.examplefield__c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try:

```
String testString = 'Account.example__c';

List<String> splitString = testString.split('\\.');

Schema.SobjectField theField = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(splitString[0]).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(splitString[1]);
```

This obviously has no error handling in it, but hopefully it gets you started.

Or breaking this down to understand it:

```
String testString = 'Account.example__c';

List<String> splitString = testString.split('\\.');

// store the object/field names
String objectName = splitString[0];
String fieldName = splitString[1];

// get the SObjectType

Schema.SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);

// get the fields on the object

Map<String, SObjectField> fieldMap = objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

// The key to the map is the api name of the field

Schema.SobjectField theField = fieldMap.get(fieldName);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yo can use [`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) method to retrieve `Map` of field of Sobject and then get desired field by name from this `Map`.
Important, that keys for sobject names and sobject field names are stored in lower case.

```
String fieldName = 'Account.OwnerId';
List<String> parts = fieldName.split('\\.');
Map<String, SObjectField> fieldsMapByName = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(parts.get(0).toLowerCase()).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
SObjectField desiredSobjField = fieldsMapByName.get(parts.get(1).toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Schema.getGlobalDescribe()** is super slow, instead, You can use **Type.forName** method:

```
String testString = 'Account.Id';
List<String> splitString = testString.split('\\.');
String objectName = splitString[0];
String fieldName = splitString[1];
    
SObjectType objectType = ((SObject)Type.forName(objectName).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
SObjectField objectField = objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName);
```

Comment: This originates from [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218982/why-is-schema-describesobjectstypes-slower-than-schema-getglobaldescribe) which has various other interesting points within it.